# Local IP address changed, can’t log in to WordPress in Ubuntu LAMP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost

In 24h my IP address has changed twice. I even created a new VM and started my website from scratch, but it happened the same after 2h.

I first tried this:

***Database changed***

```
  mysql> UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://192.168.1.3" WHERE option_value = 'http://192.168.1.9';
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec) Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0
```

But unfortunately it didn’t work. So I tried this:

```
mysql> use wordpress;

mysql> select * from wp_options where option_id=1;

mysql> update wp_options set option_value="http://192.168.1.3" where option_id=1; exit
```

And initially it seemed that it worked, because when I restarted it and checked `option_id=1` it was changed to my new IP, but when I try to open wordpress, it still doesn't work.

In the meantime, I shut off the machine and when I turned it back on, there's an error when I write the command ip addr show

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you please add the error you got when using ip addr show?
Does it also return an error if you use ifconfig?

Comment: can you reverting those and see whether its working or not. if its works then problem with your IP address. For helping give error message.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix your current problem, but you can avoid it in the future by modifying your hosts file to point a named zone to the IP and specify the name in WP config. You could also set a static IP on your router so that it doesn't change again.